# How to automatically add X-CSRF-TOKEN with jQuery ajax request in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, csrf-token

How can I add csrf token with my ajax requests (GET or POST) of my Laravel application automatically without adding it manually to each and every request.

**My ajax Request**

```
   $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url: "/email/unique",
      data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", "email": email }
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Laravel the value of the **csrf-token meta tag** registers by default with the Axios HTTP library. But If you are ***not using this library***, you will need to manually configure this behavior for your application.

To do this, store the token in a HTML meta tag

> `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Then, once you have created the meta tag, you can instruct the jQuery library to automatically add the token to all the request headers.

For that add the code to the `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file for `Laravel 5.7` and `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` for `Laravel 5.6` and below versions.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Ajax without csrf token as it will get added automatically

```
$.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url: "/email/unique",
      data: { "email": email }
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
 });
```